# how to get the following result

Tags: python, arrays

these are the index:

```
Index= [2, 3, 4, 6]
```

these are the frequency of the index, this two arrays are related by the position for instance the first element of the array Index is 2 and has frequency 2 since the element of the position 2 of the array Frequency is 2.

```
Frequency=[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

I need to get the following array labels:

```
labels=[2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6]
```

In order to get it I did the following code:

```
labels=[]

for index in Index:
    Counter=Frequency[index]
    for i in range(Counter):
        labels.append(index)

print(labels)

labels=[2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6]
```

are there any other form to optimize this process ?

Comment: By the way you present your problem we wouldn't know how to proceed either.

Comment: Probably you are not providing the full info + also show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Based on your question and Data Provided:
- I can not spot a relation between your two "input-arrays" (`frequency`, `TrainIndex`) and your output array.
- Please correct your highlighting (`frequency` is not shown as code)

Please post the code you tried so far and describe the connection between the Input Data and what shall be the output data in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the frecuency list is the same length as the TrainIndex list:

```
frecuency = [2,2,2,1]
TrainIndex = [9,4,5,8]
[g for sublist in [[i]*f for (i,f) in zip(TrainIndex,frecuency)] for g in sublist]

[9, 9, 4, 4, 5, 5, 8]
```

Comment: thanks for the support I already found the solution this is the code